# Apache commons untar: IllegalArgumentException with getNextTarEntry

Tags: java, apache, compression, tar, illegalargumentexception

I am having a problem with the [compress apache library](http://commons.apache.org/compress). I would like to untar an archive that contains binary files. Here is the code:

```java
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream;

public class ArchiveManager {

    public static final int BUFFER_MAX = 2048;

    public static void untar(String fileName, String targetPath) throws IOException {
        File tarArchiveFile = new File(fileName);
        BufferedOutputStream dest = null;
        FileInputStream tarArchiveStream = new FileInputStream(tarArchiveFile);
        TarArchiveInputStream tis = new TarArchiveInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(tarArchiveStream));
        TarArchiveEntry entry = null;
        try {
            while ((entry = tis.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
                int count;
                File outputFile = new File(targetPath, entry.getName());

                if (entry.isDirectory()) { // entry is a directory
                    if (!outputFile.exists()) {
                        outputFile.mkdirs();
                    }
                } else { // entry is a file
                    byte[] data = new byte[BUFFER_MAX];
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                    dest = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, BUFFER_MAX);
                    while ((count = tis.read(data, 0, BUFFER_MAX)) != -1) {
                        dest.write(data, 0, count);
                    }
                    dest.flush();
                    dest.close();
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (dest != null) {
                dest.flush();
                dest.close();
            }
            tis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

When untaring binary files, `getNextTarEntry()` throws an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid byte 111 at offset 0 in 'o.txt{NUL}{NUL}{NUL}' len=8
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarUtils.parseOctal(TarUtils.java:99)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry.parseTarHeader(TarArchiveEntry.java:786)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveEntry.<init>(TarArchiveEntry.java:308)
    at org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.tar.TarArchiveInputStream.getNextTarEntry(TarArchiveInputStream.java:198)
    at com.airbus.pakito.download.ArchiveManager.untar(ArchiveManager.java:22)
```

I tried to untar simple text files. After having untared the last file, `getNextTarEntry()` does not return null but an object with empty fileds. So `entry.getName()` is empty and obviously `new FileOutputStream(outputFile)` cannot create a file.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Temp (Accès refusé)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.airbus.pakito.util.Archive.untar(Archive.java:32)
```

Do you have an idea where the problem comes from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out where the problem comes from.

This is [a known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COMPRESS-178) which is fixed in the 1.4 release of Apache compress. I hope this release will be [available very soon](http://osdir.com/ml/user-commons-apache/2012-03/msg00002.html).